# Export kra (a krita document) as png

Tags: command-line, image-processing, inkscape, vector-drawings, calligra

How can I export a krita (kra) document with many layers to a png using command line?

Comment: I have no experience with krita, and don't know what a kra document is, but if you intend to convert to a png format and have many layers, you'll have to flatten the image first as png doesn't support layers. This is how I would handle a multi-layer image in Gimp. I don't believe you can do this from the command line with the document in its current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is *Calligra Converter*:

```
sudo apt-get install calligra-libs
```

run with

```
calligraconverter input_file output_file
```

---

or you could try [this solution](http://www.davidrevoy.com/data/documents/2014-06-30_UbuntuGnome1404/):

> *Artscript in Files/Nautilus*
>
> Artscript is a software to convert/watermark/glue-together on the fly
>   a big range of images format. Even SVG, *.kra and *.ora.
>
> Download and unzip Artscriptk source code in a folder. Get the last
>   [here](https://github.com/vanyossi/artscriptk/releases)
>
> - Then with Files go to `/home/<yourusername>/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
> - Create a file Artscriptk
> - `touch Artscriptk`
> - give it execution permissions
>
>   ```
>   sudo chmod +x Artscriptk
>   ```
> - and edit it:
>
>   ```
>   gedit Artscriptk
>   ```
> - paste this inside, and customise the path depending where you unzipped Artscriptk sources:
>
>   ```
>   #!/bin/sh
>   /home/<yourusernamehere>/path/to/artscriptk/artscript2.tcl $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
>   ```
>
> Now you can select files in Files/Nautilus, and do right click→script→Artscript
>   and send the files to Artscript for using it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on Linux subsystem for Windows (WSL), but for some reason it doesn't work. I figured out a quick little workaround though.

.kra files are really just archives, and they actually have 2 png versions of your image inside: `mergedimage.png` and `preview.png`. So you can just use 7z or another archiving tool to extract the `mergedimage.png`.

so in one command that would be:

`7z x my_image.kra -o. *.png`

or

`7z x my_image.kra -o. mergedimage.png`

if you only want the latter.

the `-o.` flag sets the output directory to the current directory, you might want to play around with that.